# MSDOC Batch file console application argument issue

Tags: command-line, dos

I've got a MS DOS command line issue, I'm trying to pass some arguments to a console application from a batch file as below (notice that [xemSA]" is actually on the previous  line, stackoverflow is putting it on another line) :

```
SET server=devmos
   UploadToDevMos.exe /server=server% /file="~dpdocuments\Word2003.doc" /querystring:"frequentlyused=0&clienttemplate=0&DocType=Minute&doctype=Minute&clientcodes=[xemSA]"
```

However when I run the batch file notice that the /querystring has disappeared and spaces have been put around the &

```
C:\Temp\SJ\TestRunner\bin\Debug>SET server=devmos

C:\Temp\SJ\TestRunner\bin\Debug>UploadToDevMos.exe /server=devmos /file="C:\Temp
\SJ\TestRunner\bin\Debug\"frequentlyused=0  & clienttemplate=0  & DocType=Minute
  & doctype=Minute  & clientcodes=[JTCLuxemSA]"
```

How can I pass these arguments in a batch file correctly?

Kind regards

Simon Jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something to do with the `~dp0` not expanding as expected.  I think you missed the "0"

I changed my test to this, and it worked okay:

```
SET server=devmos

ECHO UploadToDevMos.exe /server=%server% /file="%~dp0documents\Word2003.doc" /querystring:"frequentlyused=0&clienttemplate=0&DocType=Minute&doctype=Minute&clientcodes=[xemSA]"
```

Comment: That's the answer, thank you very much.  I had an extra % at the end of %~dp0

Answer (score 1):

one of your parameters is using `=` and the other one is using `:` like `/file=` and `/querystring:`. I suspect both of them should use the same character.

Comment: That might upset the UploadToDevMos programme, but the problem here is before that app even gets going.

Comment: Red herring I'm afraid. I'm parsing the arguments in the exe and I accept either, the issue is in the batch file.